# Flutter WebSocketChannel.connect with access_token

Tags: flutter, websocket

I am trying to use the Flutter with WebSockets as shown in the sample: [Communicate with WebSockets](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/web-sockets)
I am showing the MyHomePage screen after login and by passing access_token  I get after I login. I am passing access_token in the build() function like so:

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  late final _channel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final urlStr = 'wss://example.websocket.com/dev?access_token=${widget.token}';
      //final urlStr = 'wss://echo.websocket.events'; 
      _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(urlStr),);

    return Scaffold(...
```

This does not work. But when I replace the urlStr ***without*** the access_token and use the wss url just like the original sample, it works.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final urlStr = 'wss://echo.websocket.events'; 
    _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(urlStr),);
    ...
```

it works. What am I doing wrong and how should I be passing the access_token? any help would be greatly appreciated.